# Jupyter notebook inspect variable in module imported

Tags: python, debugging, jupyter-notebook

I'd like to understand how a module works I import in my jupyter notebook python script. It's easy to see and monitor the variables in my notebook. But how can I access variable inside the module? I found the hint to make them temporarily global. But this doesn't work in jupyter notebook and modifying external code for inspection might not be the most elegant way.

What it the best way to inspect variables inside an imported nodule?